# "Including x" (as a note) in French?

Tags: expressions

I want to write when my university studies started and ended.

Something like "Six years (including a gap year).

There are several translations to "include/including", and I don't know which to use.

Does "Six ans (dont une année sabbatique)" work?

Comment: L'expression "dont une année sabbatique" est  correcte, si c'est juste une note ça devrait aller, sinon il faudrait voir comment tu l'intègres dans le reste de la phrase.

Comment: On the side note, I think "année de césure" is a more appropriate translation of "gap year"

Comment: @Laure Pas de verbe?

Comment: @Micromégas non, sans verbe, le "dont" rend l'idée contenu dans *including*, plus habituel que *y compris* dans ce cas.

Comment: @Christophe I read that année sabbatique was correct :) I don't have the feel for it, but I assume both work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Six ans (dont une année sabbatique)` works.

But depending on the context, other forms might be preferable.

For instance, if you used the `"(dont ....)"` form several times just before or after this one, repetition might make your style look heavy and unappealing, or worse viewed as a hint that the writer don't know the french language enough to use variations.

Another form you can use is `Six ans (comprenant une année sabbatique)`.

But I wouldn't use `Six ans (y compris une année sabbatique)`, even though it's very close to the former.
It's not exactly proper for your purpose here.

Answer (score 1):

Si c'est pour un CV professionnel, présenter les choses ainsi me paraît inapproprié : c'est assimiler l'année sabbatique aux études alors que c'est justement l'inverse qui s'est produit. Il vaudrait peut-être mieux détailler ces différentes périodes.